# Low Search Secure Action

Tags: low-search, secure, secureforms

I'm using Low Search 2.1.2 on a Shop page.  The search works fine, but the padlock for the SSL cert is coming up as broken.  Inspecting it in Chrome gives the following error: The page at example.com was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'example.com'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

It seems to be Low Search form, which is creating the following HTML:

```
<form id="main_search" method="post" action="http://example.com/index.php">
```

I've used the following tag to generate the form:

```
{exp:low_search:form form_id="main_search" collection="products" search_mode="all" result_page="/shop/results" force_protocol="https"}
```

Is there a way to make Low Search generate a secure action URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is true for **any form generated by EE**, including the Low Search form:

If you want the `action` url to be https, make sure the **URL to the root directory of your site** setting under Admin > General Configuration (aka the `site_url` config item) also starts with https.